# Nested loop: html table that is badly laid out

Tags: angular

By having a nested loop, I don't understand why the HTML table is badly arranged?

[image]

I thought it was an HTML/CSS problem but I feel like it's a problem with my loops?

```
  <table class="mb-5">
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Vote</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container>
      <tr *ngFor="let l of MET">
        <td>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let l of l.RESOLUTION">
            <tr>
              <td>{{ l.REF }}</td>
              <td>{{ l.ISSOUMISAUVOTE }}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
```

There is a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ynezv?file=src/main.component.html).

I've never had this problem, if you have a solution, I'm very interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer loop needs to be a `ng-container` too, otherwise you will have an extra `<tr>` wrapping (check the produced HTML).

```
<div class="container text-center" *ngIf="MET">
  <h2 class="pt-3 pb-3">HTML Table</h2>
  <table class="mb-5">
    <tr>
      <th>Isin</th>
      <th>Denomination</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let line of MET">
      <td>{{ line.ISINCODE }}</td>
      <td>{{ line.LABEL }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <table class="mb-5">
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Vote</th>
    </tr>
    <ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let l of MET">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let l of l.RESOLUTION">
            <tr>
              <td>{{ l.REF }}</td>
              <td>{{ l.ISSOUMISAUVOTE }}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right. There are some mistakes in ngFor loops.
Here is the solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yuhcwb